# Memory Leak: Potential leak of an object allocated on line

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my first post so I hope the formatting is ok.

I'm getting this leak "Potential leak of an object on line" and I can't figure it out. Perhaps I'm looking at it too hard and therefore I can't see the problem. Could someone help me out?

The line is question is: appDelegate.imageText

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PListFirstAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PListFirstAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    appDelegate.imageText= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];

    //NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.imageText);

    NavigationalDescription *detailViewController = [[NavigationalDescription alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationalDescription" bundle:nil];


     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an autorelease call at the end of that line.
iPad won't let me copy paste code :( so no example right now.

```
appDelegate.imageText= [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"] ] autorelease];
```

You are saying delegating control over the memory management to the imagetext instance. They should retain the string as they need it.

Comment: Glad it worked, you should accept an answer for future reference by others.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use any init method to instantiate an object, you must release it somewhere, or call autorelease.

Class methods that return something should always be autoreleased.

So instead of using `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat...]`

do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myString]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace code at

```
 appDelegate.imageText= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
```

with

```
appDelegate.imageText= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
```

Comment: If you are working on new project, then it would be great if you could start using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
appDelegate.imageText= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
```

you are assigning an allocated string to image text property. the property assignment should  be to an autoreleased string. imageText should be a retain property, therefore retaining the falue of the string being assigned to it. If it's retain, you are double retaining, therefore leaking the object.